# deploy via capistrano fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, mercurial, capistrano

```
2013-06-17 15:23:22 executing `deploy'
* 2013-06-17 15:23:22 executing `deploy:update'
** transaction: start
* 2013-06-17 15:23:22 executing `deploy:update_code'
updating the cached checkout on all servers
executing locally: "hg log --verbose -r tip --template \"{node|short}\""
command finished in 74ms
* executing "if [ -d /home/user/shared/cached-copy ]; then hg pull --verbose --repository /home/user/shared/cached-copy ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/myapp && hg update --verbose --repository /home/user/shared/cached-copy --clean 70d2fc5e4a40; else hg clone --verbose --noupdate ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/myapp /home/user/shared/cached-copy && hg update --verbose --repository /home/user/shared/cached-copy --clean 70d2fc5e4a40; fi"

[192.168.1.204] executing command
** [192.168.1.204 :: out] running ssh hg@bitbucket.org 'hg -R user/myapp serve --stdio'
** [192.168.1.204 :: out] pulling from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/myapp    ** [192.168.1.204 :: out] searching for changes
** no changes found
** [192.168.1.204 :: out] remote: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '207.223.240.182' to the list of known hosts.
** [192.168.1.204 :: out] abort: unknown revision '70d2fc5e4a40'!
```

i made a deploy.rb script to deploy a rails application via capistrano the problem is that when i run cap deploy there is something wrong with the cloning process and id on't know what this revision is. this is my deploy.rb :
    require "rvm/capistrano"
    require "bundler/capistrano"

```
set :application, "myapp"
set :use_sudo , false
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :rvm_type, :user                      
set :rvm_install_with_sudo, true
set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"") 
set :scm, :mercurial
set :repository,  "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/myapp"
set :deploy_to, "/home/user/"
set :user, "user"
set :scm_verbose, true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

can anyone help me?

PS : i forget to tell that my repository has two sub repositories would that be the problem or do i need to set any options for that?

Comment: Try removing the cached-copy folder in /home/user/shared/

Comment: Can you confirm you have pushed your latest commit (70d2fc5e4a40) to bitbucket?

Comment: Jesse Wolgamott do you mean that the problem can be that i still have local uncommited changes?

Comment: @Vimsha i removed the cached-copy folder then ran the deploy same result

Comment: @JesseWolgamott i commited all local changes and push it to the repository then tried the deploy again but same result

Comment: oh mercurcial, ugh, sorry I'm out